# Deobfuscation Settings Android

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, deobfuscation

I have added all the options suggested in the Firebase documentation.

[Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android)

and in my proguard-rules.txt

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

but still I get some cryptic crashlytics information.

for example

```
       Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
       at com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager.folders.browseLocalFoldersActivity.a(PlaylistManager:20)
       at com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager.android.f$b.a(PlaylistManager:3)
       at com.flyingdutchman.newplaylistmanager.android.g$a.onClick(PlaylistManager:2)
```

What else is required ? 
ps It used to be far more explicit before the latest Android Studio upgrade and this has regressed imho

Comment: I have the same issue, partially deobfuscated method names and incorrect line numbers. I suspect this is related with the R8 compiler which is automatically enabled if you are using Gradle plugin 3.4.0 or higher, since the deobfuscation worked correctly before R8 was introduced.